# Is it possible to remove camera frame but still continue detection in command prompt console?

Tags: opencv, object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I am working with YOLOv4 for detection through IP Camera. I have a GUI for camera control. So I don't want the camera frame to show the detected objects. However, I want the detected objects and the percentage to be shown in the Command Prompt console. Is it possible to make that? If yes, please suggest the way. Thank You

Comment: no, you are expected to show code and some issue with it. this isn't a code writing service. please review the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-dont_show` after the command